# Adding multiple select boxes in javascript dynamically to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
selectBox1 = document.createElement("select");
selectBox2 = document.createElement("select");
selectBox1.setAttribute("id","select1");
selectBox2.setAttribute("id","select2");

tr = document.createElement('tr');
for(var k = 1; k<headers.length; k++){
 var op = new Option();
 var op1 = new Option();
 op.value = op1.value= headers[k];
 op.text = op1.text =  headers[k];
 selectBox1.options.add(op);
 selectBox2.options.add(op);      
  th = document.createElement('th');
  th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(headers[k]));

  tr.appendChild(th);

}
document.getElementById("table").appendChild(selectBox1);
document.getElementById("table").appendChild(selectBox2);
```

When I use op object and insert the option in the 1st and 2nd select box, only the 2nd select box is populated and 1st one is empty. I've to take two option objects. Why is that so? It's not a problem but I  want to understand why it's happening.

Comment: what are you using `op1` for here?

Comment: Even I am wondering how this is happening but since you are already creating one more option `op1` try adding that as option **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/w104mxjv/)**

Answer (score 3):

What you need to know if you **selectBox1.options.add(op)** you will add op to selectBox1 options then when you do **selectBox2.options.add(op)** it will remove it from selectBox1 options and add it to selectBox2 options.

[image]

use that **op1**

```
selectBox1.options.add(op1);
selectBox2.options.add(op);
```

Comment: I don't think so buddy. It will not remove the option and add it to another when you use `add`! But yea this solution works!

Comment: You have taked an html element and put it in another element **yes** he do remove it from the first.

Comment: I think you are right.. But its not because of `add` but its because of `pass by reference` concept!

Answer (score 0):

**Why this is happening**

I feel this is happening because of <kbd>**`pass by reference`**</kbd> concept.

So consider this line

```
var op=new Option()
```

A reference to the `option` object will be created and the above line will be equivalent to

```
var op=document.createElement('option')
```

> So what happens here is once a `reference` to the `object` is created
>   that `reference` can be assigned to only one `element` at a time. That
>   is why `adding` and `removal` of `option` is happening and the same
>   `reference` will be given to 2nd `select` and if you see in `DOM`
>   perspective there will be only one `option` element created and it can
>   be assigned to only `select` element. A fact the `coding language` or
>   `html` follows.

**Conclusion**

Either you have to create a new `reference` as you are doing now like `op`,`op1` or you can directly use below line without any extra code of creating `option` assigning `text` and `value` to it etc.,

```
selectBox1.options.add(new Option(headers[k],headers[k]));
selectBox2.options.add(new Option(headers[k],headers[k]));
```

A sample **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/w104mxjv/1/)**

Hope this makes sense and reference for my explanation - **[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536389(v=vs.85).aspx)** where in they have stated :

> ***Before you use new objects, you must explicitly add them to their
>   respective collections or to the document.***