# How to dynamically add n select elements with options in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn how to dynamically add n select elements with options to an HTML form using vanilla JS. There are a few related Stack Overflow questions but these focus on instances where you know how many select elements there will be [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577286/updating-multiple-select-boxes-dynamically) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849048/adding-multiple-select-boxes-in-javascript-dynamically-to-dom). I don't know exactly how many select elements will need to be generated; I need to generate them dynamically. I started simpler by learning how to dynamically generate regular text fields:

```
for (let i = 0; i < res[0].length; i++) {
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(res[0][i])); 
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = res[1][i]; 
    input.name = res[0][i];
    input.classList.add("input");
    container.appendChild(input);
}
```

where

```
var res = [["textfield 1","text field 2"],["text","text"],[["none"],["none"]]];
```

That works fine for regular text fields so then I started working on  select elements:

```
for (let i = 0; i < res[0].length; i++) {
      var select = document.getElementById("mySelect"); 
      var options = res[2][i];
      for(var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
          var optn = options[j];

          var elmnt = document.createElement("option");
          elmnt.name = res[0][i];
          elmnt.classList.add("input")
          elmnt.text = optn;
          elmnt.value = optn;
          select.id = res[0][i];
          select.add(elmnt);
                                            
                  }
}
```

where

```
var res = [["country","language"],["li","li"],[["Canada","Mexico","United States"],["English","Spanish","English"]]];
```

I thought that using `select.id = res[0][i];` would accomplish what I want but I think that's just creating separate sets of *options* and not actually creating separate select *elements*. Right now, this yields the first select with countries but the second select for languages doesn't appear.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>  

    <form name="myTest" id="myTest_frm">
      
    <div id="container"/>
    <select multiple = true id="mySelect">
    <option>Select an option</option>
    </select>
    
    </div>
  
    <br><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="test()">
    </form>
```

I know that I can modify the HTML to include multiple select tags to make this work as shown below but that requires that I pre-know how many select elements I'll need. Again, I don't pre-know how many select elements there will be, i.e. `res[0].length` could be two as shown in the examples or it could be any other length.

Working but not dynamic:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>  

    <form name="myTest" id="myTest_frm">
      
    <div id="container"/>
    <select multiple = true id="mySelect">
    <option>Select an option</option>
    </select>

    <select multiple = true id="mySelect">
    <option>Select an option</option>
    </select>
    
    </div>
  
    <br><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="test()">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need establish the format of your dynamic data.

```
var res = [["country","language"],["li","li"],[["Canada","Mexico","United States"],["English","Spanish","English"]]]
```

This is a difficult to work with format, as it's "hard-coded" position of the list in the array (what's the `li` are for?)

For your purpose you probably should go with an object which contains list of options (array).
This way, you can use object's key for `select` name:

```js
var res = {
  country: ["Mexico" /*default*/, "Canada","Mexico","United States"],
  language: ["French" /*default*/, "English","Spanish","French"]
}

const container = document.getElementById("container");
for(let i in res)
{
  const select = document.createElement("select");
  select.value = res[i].shift(); //select default item, by removing first item from the array
  container.appendChild(select);

  for(let o = 0; o < res[i].length; o++)
  {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.textContent = res[i][o];
    option.value = res[i][o];
    select.appendChild(option);
  };

}
```

```html
<form name="myTest" id="myTest_frm">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <br><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="test()">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @vanowm. You're right about the data structure. My original code uses an object; I should've just simplified it for this example. I'm using `li` to indicate list. The actual form contains text fields and select fields. `res[1]` is used to indicate what type of field. In case it helps someone, I added `select.multiple="multiple";` to get multi-select elements.

Comment: You can expand this by additional parameters for each item with something like this:
`var res = { country: {multiple: true, blah: "ok", options: ["Mexico" /*default*/, "Canada","Mexico","United States"]}}` than you'd need use `res[i].options` to get list of options and `res[i].multiple` and `res[i].blah` for other parameters.